# No GNATtest in GNAT Community Edition?

Tags: ada, gnat

When I try to generate unit tests in GNAT 2020 Community Edition (Windows 10 64 bit), I get an error on missing gnattest tool: `could not locate gnattest`.
Same happens on Ubuntu 20.04 (in WSL) with package gnat-10: `could not locate x86_64-linux-gnu-gnattest-10`.

Is GNATtest not part of GNAT 2020 Community Edition, as shown on AdaCores website (https://www.adacore.com/gnatpro/comparison)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes in 2020 Community Edition `gnattest` is not included. Main reason: `gnattest` is tool based on library **ASIS** which is no longer maintained. AdaCore is moving towards **libadalang** library and for now `gnattest` is a victim of these changes. It will back soon or later to Community Edition (when it will be rewritten to use **libadalang**). Source: I was hit by this same problem and I got this answer from AdaCore :)

At this moment, you can download source package `asis-2019-20190517-18AB5-src.tar.gz` from previous version of GNAT and compile it by self. At least for me, it works.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu you can just install asis applications with : sudo apt install asis-programs

Answer (score 2):

AdaCore are moving away from ASIS to their own libadalang technology, and GNAT CE 2020 doesn’t include ASIS.

The ASIS-based applications in GNAT CE 2019 are

```
gnat2xml
gnat2xsd
gnatcheck
gnatelim
gnatmetric *
gnatpp *
gnatstub *
gnattest
```

of which only the ones marked with an asterisk are in GNAT CE 2020 (for macOS, at any rate).

If you do go with @thindil’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62406850/40851), it’d be best to install the ASIS tools in their own directory, so as to avoid stomping on `gnatpp` etc.

For info, `gnatelim` is missing because - for targets using the GNU linker - `-ffunction-sections`, `-fdata-sections`, and `-gc-sections` do the equivalent job